# Train Neural network with image pixels as input and get the screen coordinate value as output in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network, pixel, training-data

I am a newbie in the neural network, in my project I need to implement a neural network that uses image pixels as input and will give screen coordinate value as output. I am having Dataset which I have collected by performing an experiment by many volunteers. In details, I need to give only cropped eye pixel into the neural network for training. the cropped eye is of size 30*30 (approx) after resizing. I have created a dataset of users looking at a different specific point on the screen. Each point is on a specific coordinate and that is known to me. It is basically an implementation of one research paper.

If you can suggest me, how should I process to create the Neural network that it would be a great help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use input image as input to neural network, you can use Conventional Neural Network. CNN can gives image as input.

If you want to extract feature from image, you can use MLP neural network.